# Removing a decimal from a float then compare to another value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe that I'm working with in pandas. I have two columns that I want to determine if they're not equal. An example of the data is as follows:

```
           A          B         Compare
1002      3.1         31        Not Equal
1003       5          5         
1004       1          3         Not Equal
```

I want rows like the first one (1002) to show as equal because they contain the same numbers. Both columns A and B are float64 data types.

I have tried the following:

```
df['column_a'].replace('.','')
```

And I've also attempted to find a way to multiply a number by 10 on the condition that the value is not an integer (3.1, 2.2, 1.4, etc).

I believe I could also accomplish the same desired end result by taking all values that are greater than 5 in column B and divide them by 10. I only care about values 0 through 5. The only values I'm going to see above 5 can be divided by 10.

This is what I tried doing to accomplish that but I get an error (TypeError: invalid type comparison):

```
df['column_b'] = np.where(df['column_b'] > 5, /10,'')
```

What would be the best way to make the values equal in column A and B for row 1002?

Comment: what if you try to first convert your float number into `string`, then remove the decimal point, and finally convert it back to `integer`? E.g. `int(str(num).replace(".",""))` where `num` is your float number

Comment: I think you are on the right track with trying to remove the periods. You will need to probably use the `.apply()` method on both columns and convert them both to strings and remove decimal points from the left one. Then you will be able to compare them.

Comment: @Stephen If your columns really are float64, then '31' would be represented as 31.0, same is case with 5 as '5.0'. Please clarify, what are you trying to do in that case ? Will 3.1 will be considered equal to 31.0 ?

Answer (score -1):

This is worth the try:

`df['Compare'] = df['A'].str.replace(".","").astype(int).eq(df['B'])`

You were going in the right direction, just add `astype` and use `.eq()` ..

Comment: When I tried this, it ends up making Column A two digits for each entry. Column A is now `[31 50 10]`